# Query Regarding the Session time out in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have hosted a web application in the IIS, And I am using the system Idle Time = 20 minutes (default).

But I face the problem like It gets logged off before that when I am idle for sometime less than 20 minutes.(Note: Client and Server are different here)

And I found a log entry in the server as

```
2013-01-07 06:54:32 <ClientIPAddress> 1101 <server IP Address> 86 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

And

```
2013-01-07 06:36:14 <client IPAddress> 56282 <server IPAddress> 86 HTTP/1.1 GET /LogOffPage.aspx?SessionExpired=Y&FromPage=%2fajaxpro%Common.ashx - 2 Connection_Dropped TestApp
```

what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what the log says. Does that mean that it took 19 minutes instead of 20 to timeout?

Comment: yes.. it has timed out before 20 mins

Comment: Does that happen to the last user connected to the app (are you the only one using it)? Or when there are still other users using the app?

Comment: I was checking with a single user

Comment: Have you set the executionTimeout in web.config - <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600"/>

Comment: @Umesh yes I have already set the executionTimeout to 2800

Comment: Please, don't forget to let us know the solution. Thx and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but I think it is worth trying.

There are 2 things going on in IIS ASP.NET apps. One is the idle-timeout which is when IIS shuts down the application when it stays idle. The other is **session timeout**. It may be that the **idle-timeout** (which is also 20 min) might be causing this. **As you are a single user when you stay idle you are causing both of these to happen together**.

Leave session time-out at 20min. Son not change it.

Bu set idle-timeout to 30min. End track again your session time-out.

I'm attaching a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: thanks @erich007,  I have tried that but that is not the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*[As the fellow peers stated before, there's little info to work upon...]*

On IIS 7.0, for .Net applications, session life span depends on several settings.

- 'Idle Time' from the Pool settings <sup>(1)</sup>
- 'Cookie timeout' from the application's Authentication settings
- 'Session timeout' from the application's Session State settings
- 'sessionState timeout' when specified within system.web section at the web.config file

<sup>(1)</sup> this is valid for applications with Session State set to 'InProc'

Please, check all of these configurations to ensure that these settings are set for 20 minutes (1200 seconds) or more.

Also, via Google, I've found reports of 'Connection_Dropped' events due to insufficient memory or server-side script execution time-out.

You may check for such events with with Window's PerfMon.

The information from the following links may be useful:

- official document on 'InProc' session destruction:
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324772/en-us
- official document on PerfMon for .Net applications:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4(v=vs.85).aspx
- official source on 'Pool Idle Time-out':
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx
- rather bold statement on this setting:
   [How to prevent/extend idleTimeout in IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891178/how-to-prevent-extend-idletimeout-in-iis-7)
- maybe ConnectionTimeout setting has to be considered:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sitelimits.connectiontimeout(v=vs.90).aspx
- more on ConnectionTimeout:
   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/73566f83-c257-4941-8ed8-7ae45b2e7985.mspx?mfr=true
- last, but not least, this document may be useful:
   http://ramanisandeep.net/2011/03/19/tipstrick-session-timeout-problem-in-iis7/

Good luck!

P.S.: sorry for the lack of screen snapshots ilustrating the settings at IIS. My OS is in portuguese...

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information about your configuration but...

Perhaps your application pool is recycling or shutting down when idle, which is causing the InProc session to also expire before it should? If this is the cause you need to edit your App Pool settings and retest.